# override background color from a div without class with nth-child?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to change the background color from all the div under the div with `class=hamburger-react`.

I don't have access to this piece of html, so I need to target the good div and !important override.

I tried with :

```css
 div.close-overlay-btn:nth-child(2)  {
    background: rgba(0, 100, 172, 0.411) !important;
    }
```

```html
     <div class="close-overlay-btn">
     <div class="hamburger-react" aria-expanded="true" role="button" tabindex="0" style="cursor: pointer; height: 48px; position: relative; transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s; user-select: none; width: 48px; outline: none; transform: rotate(-180deg);">
      <div style="background: #dc3545;height: 3px;left: 8px;position: absolute;width: 32px;top: 13px;transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s;transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-7.07px, 7.07px);"></div>
      <div style="background: rgb(255, 221, 2); height: 3px; left: 8px; position: absolute; width: 32px; top: 23px; transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s; opacity: 0;"></div>
      <div style="background: rgb(255, 221, 2); height: 3px; left: 8px; position: absolute; width: 32px; top: 33px; transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s; transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7.07px, -7.07px);"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

But didnt work.

Any tips ? since these div have no class it's a little bit more complicated than expected

Comment: Do you mean `div.close-overlay-btn > div > div` ?

Comment: please try  div.close-overlay-btn div div:nth-child(3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really can't access/change the `HTML`, then the easy way is really using `!important` (which I do not advise in general) <sup>***Solution 1***</sup>

Other - better - solution, is remove the inline styles with JavaScript - and implement the same CSS but without `!important` <sup>***Solution 2***</sup>

---

You are using your selector the wrong way, try this:

```
.hamburger-react div
```

This will affect every div child of `.hamburger-react`

#### Solution 1

```css
.hamburger-react div {
  background: rgba(0, 100, 172, 0.411) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="close-overlay-btn">
  <div class="hamburger-react" aria-expanded="true" role="button" tabindex="0" style="cursor: pointer; height: 48px; position: relative; transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s; user-select: none; width: 48px; outline: none; transform: rotate(-180deg);">
    <div style="background: #dc3545;height: 3px;left: 8px;position: absolute;width: 32px;top: 13px;transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s;transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-7.07px, 7.07px);"></div>
    <div style="background: rgb(255, 221, 2); height: 3px; left: 8px; position: absolute; width: 32px; top: 23px; transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s; opacity: 0;"></div>
    <div style="background: rgb(255, 221, 2); height: 3px; left: 8px; position: absolute; width: 32px; top: 33px; transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s; transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7.07px, -7.07px);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Solution 2

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.hamburger-react div').forEach(el => el.style.removeProperty('background'))
```

```css
.hamburger-react div {
  background: rgba(0, 100, 172, 0.411);
}
```

```html
<div class="close-overlay-btn">
  <div class="hamburger-react" aria-expanded="true" role="button" tabindex="0" style="cursor: pointer; height: 48px; position: relative; transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s; user-select: none; width: 48px; outline: none; transform: rotate(-180deg);">
    <div style="background: #dc3545;height: 3px;left: 8px;position: absolute;width: 32px;top: 13px;transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s;transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-7.07px, 7.07px);"></div>
    <div style="background: rgb(255, 221, 2); height: 3px; left: 8px; position: absolute; width: 32px; top: 23px; transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s; opacity: 0;"></div>
    <div style="background: rgb(255, 221, 2); height: 3px; left: 8px; position: absolute; width: 32px; top: 33px; transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s; transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7.07px, -7.07px);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your reference in your selectors is invalid. Try this:

```css
.close-overlay-btn>.hamburger-react>div {}
```

There is no `:nth-child(2)` to `.close-overlay-btn`.

`.close-overlay-btn` is the grandparent, `.hamburger-react` is the parent, and all of the other divs nested in `.hamburger-react` are the children to the parent.

```css
.close-overlay-btn>.hamburger-react>div {
  background: rgba(0, 100, 172, 0.411) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="close-overlay-btn">
  <div class="hamburger-react" aria-expanded="true" role="button" tabindex="0" style="cursor: pointer; height: 48px; position: relative; transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s; user-select: none; width: 48px; outline: none; transform: rotate(-180deg);">
    <div style="background: #dc3545;height: 3px;left: 8px;position: absolute;width: 32px;top: 13px;transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s;transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-7.07px, 7.07px);"></div>
    <div style="background: rgb(255, 221, 2); height: 3px; left: 8px; position: absolute; width: 32px; top: 23px; transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s; opacity: 0;"></div>
    <div style="background: rgb(255, 221, 2); height: 3px; left: 8px; position: absolute; width: 32px; top: 33px; transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1) 0s; transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7.07px, -7.07px);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```